# How do I find eulerian paths in a mixed directed/undirected graph?

Tags: graph

How do I find paths that traverse all edges in a graph of vertices and edges where some edges are directed and some aren't? I want the minimum number of paths that will cover the graph.

I know about Heirholtz's algorithm and I know how to apply it to a graph that has only directed edges or only undirected edges. But I don't know how to do it on a graph that has both types of edges.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and wrote my solution here:
https://github.com/pcb2gcode/pcb2gcode/blob/master/eulerian_paths.hpp

The input is a list of edges such that each edge is labelled with "true" or "false", true means that the path is bidirectional.

We use the Hierholtz algorithm.  First, we identify nodes that *must* be the start of a path.  That's any node that has more out paths than in paths.  to compute that:

1. If the number of unidirectional out edges is greater than the sum of the number of in/bidi edges, it's definitely the start of a path.
2. If the number of unidirectional in edges is greater than the sum of the bidi and out edges, it's definitely not the start of a path.
3. If it's none of those two then, if the sum of in/out/bidi edges is odd then it must be a start of a path.

Now, pick a random path that has to be a start.  Begin the Hierholtz traversal, walking any unused edge until you reach a dead-end.  Always prefer to walk out on an out edge rather than a bidi edge because the bidi edge might be necessary as an in edge.

After each traversal reached a dead end, start again with picking a node that must be a start (taking into account all the edges that were removed), and do another traversal.  Do this restart over and over until all the edges are traversed.  You will end up with a bunch of paths, some of them will be have the same start and end point, some will not, just depending if there are eulerian paths in your graph.

At the end, there will be no paths that have an odd count of edges because if there was odd, it would have already been traversed by the Hierholzer.  Now we can stitch them together.  For each path that we found, traverse looking for unvisited edges.  If we find one, make a path from there.  Because we already did Hierholzer on all possible starts, all the paths that we found will necessarily be loops.  So just stitch those loops into the path.

Now we're done but there still might be some edges because there can be islands, like a tiny loop that did have the "must start" quality from above yet also aren't attached to another of the "must start" paths.  So just do another processing of all the remaining nodes, which will all make loops.

Done!  The code is part of `pcb2gcode` which is used for milling PCBs.

Answer (score -1):

You convert the undirected edges into two directed edges, and then run it on a directed graph.

Comment: But that will travel the undirected edges twice, once in each direction.  It won't work.

Comment: Would it be possible to link the two directed edges produced from one undirected edge such that if one of the directed edges were visited, then the other would also be marked visited?